# iTunes/Playlist application that allows reordering of songs on phone

Tags: android, music

So I like to reorder the songs on the phone and computer.

Is there an app that supports this (preferably free or cheap)?

Both Play Music and Spotify don't support this on Android([Here is a picture of this on the iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B287Z.png)).  This may have changed in future versions but this is the case for Lollipop.

Comment: I believe Google Play Music Premium supports this but is not free.  This doesn't integrate with Google Play Music but works with physical mp3s https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ferret.freemusic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great news at least on my Moto G 5.1 device you can reorder song on the phone now!!!  Simply use the double arrows on the left hand side.

[image]